# Windows 8 boot info lost after ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8

There were some similar questions but I really didn't understand.

I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu!

I had 4 drives:

```
C: NTFS (For Windows 8)
D: EXT4 (For Ubuntu)
E: NTFS (Persoanl Storgae)
F: NTFS (Persoanl Storage)
```

I had Windows 8, Then I installed Ubuntu 15, Now my computer only boot Ubuntu, What should I do to restore Windows 8 boot.

When I installed Ubuntu, I deleted the D: drive then it became free space, then I add partition in installation page, then I set it as / and EXT4 and the drive for installation.

Comment: Which question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using grub but it's not detecting windows try:

```
sudo update-grub
```

result will be like:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-21-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-18-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
```

if you spot your loader in there then it's working

Comment: Can u tell me more about it, what is its phillosophy?

Comment: well probably grub didn't notice the windows bootloader the first time you installed it, when you enter linux you can force it to recheck/update it's boot list, happened to me once in the same scenario

Comment: is there any command to check before restart computer, for example some command which list bootables?

Comment: @Milad well if you use update-grub it will shoud you the bootloaders it finds

Comment: Another question,  I'm gonna reinstall window 8, If do it, it will kill Ubuntu boot, won't it?

Comment: How can I run such a command in Windows 8.1?

Comment: @Milad well the command runs in linux and i don't trust windows to be my default bootload, i use https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair to restore it back to grub and to load all my entry points, sometimes it detects both but i still dont use it